# Youtube API Integromat testing app - connection getting disabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, make.com

I don't have much idea about API but I managed setup Youtube API so that I am able to use Integromat workflow between Youtube and Airtable.

It works fine.

The issue I have is the connection between my Youtube API at Integroat is getting disconnected after a few days / weeks and have to re-verify(reconnect) to Google account again.

The Youtube app was setup properly (as instructed by Integromat) and as I said it works..... it's grabbing URLs of new Youtube videos on my Youtube channel and it is pushing those URLs into Airtable.

Now have even added mysef now as the user of the app. Wasn't listed as the user there (1 out of 100). Could that be the reason?

The Youtube API is setup as a test-app.  Is that the reason for the disconnects at Integromat?

Do Ineed to request Google to have the app verified? Or can I continue with the app being a test app? (Because it says it hasn't been verified).

I don't know much about what I am doing but it sees working fine for me so I guess I managed to set it up OK except for the one issue with connection loss.

Pic:
[image: pic]

[image: pic]

The 2nd and 3rd item on the 2nd picture is for the Youtube API connection... and that is where I am being asked every now and then by Integromat to reconnnect the connection.. then I need to login and  Google wanrs me my application wasn't approved so I pick continue etc...

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] always remember to include a [example] as part of your question and describe the issues you are having with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue I have is the connection between my Youtube API at Integroat is getting disconnected after a few days / weeks and have to re-verify(reconnect) to Google account again.

This is because your authorization has an expire time.   Access tokens by default work for one hour.  If you want your application to refresh its access then you need to request offline access and store the refresh token and then use that to refresh your access whenever you need it.

On unverified apps refresh tokens will expire after a very short time this is because your application is considered to still be in development. YOu should apply for verification when you are ready to go to production. until that time you will need to login again regularly but as you are in development this sholdnt be to much of a problem.

Comment: Its hard to know what the author is doing really without more information Hence my close vote.  I can delete this and we can wait for them to respond if you like.  PS don't be sorry im always happy to get your help and input with questions :)

Comment: You're right: cannot know for sure. I'm not expecting that you delete your answer at all.

Comment: The answer is correct. Thanks for explanation. It helps. I assumed I didn't need to do that since I am going to be the only user, but I understand now, I need to do that regardless. I will need to get the app verified into production. Thank you all.