# Google Cloud app verification step: Your app will be available to any user with a Google Account? What does it mean?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, make.com

I have created a Youtube API application to enable access to Youtube API for Integromat. All my Youtube API application does it gives access to my Youtube channel videos for Integromat. Integromat grabs the links to videos and uploads the links to my Airtable.  So the only user for the Youtube API is going to be myself and my own Integromat workflow.

The Youtube API app is in development. I want to verify the app to get rid of the 1-hour deactivation of the authorization (Integromat connection to Youtube API breaks after 1 hour).

To get verified, I looked the steps here https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en. The first step it tells me to do is "Update the OAuth consent screen details" and I go to that screen and shows the publishing status. Do I click to "publish to production"?

When I click that, it tells me:

**Your app will be available to any user with a Google Account.**

[Screenshot showing the step to publish my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru3oX.png)

That's sounds scary. What does it mean?

I do not need (nor want) have other users logging to my Youtube API. I am the only user and Integromat is the only app that will access the Youtube API.

I am novice in this and don't have much idea about programming so I don't even know what questions I should be asking here.

Thanks.

Here are more details about what I am trying to do in Integromat:
[Youtube API Integromat testing app - connection getting disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66928633/youtube-api-integromat-testing-app-connection-getting-disabled)

Comment: Because you selected `External`, your app is available for anyone with a Google account. Change the `User Type` to `Internal` (click the `MAKE INTERNAL` button in your screenshot).

Comment: Thanks both of you.  I went to change the user type to internal it says ...I need to be a Google Workspace account user... to be able to change to internal.  When I go sign up for Google Workspace it says I have to pay, but when I search online it says Google Workspace Individual is available for free... for Gmail accounts.  Is the free Google Workspace account going to work? The YouTube account I have for the API app is non-gmail account.  So I need to create new gmail account.  So wondering if that free Google Workspace will allow setting the app to INTERNAL. All VERY confusing for me....

Comment: I do not believe Google **Workspace Individual** will be free. The service has not been released yet, so details might change. You can sign up for updates here: https://inthecloud.withgoogle.com/gws-individual/dl-cd.html Since I have not used the new **Individual** version of Workspace, I cannot answer, but I expect that it will work for your use case. Google also offers Google Identity Platform which is free: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform

Answer (score 0):

It means that you will be able to share your app via that link with anyone you please. The whole point of an API is that it's available publicly, at least on a technical level. Whether you're actively soliciting users is an entirely other matter, naturally.

Comment: Thank you.  If I don't share the app with anybody (and the app is set as "EXTERNAL",  is there any risk of people to randomly being able to find the app and abuse it in some way my account?   I'm trying to understand what is the risk.  

This API app is for my Integromat account. So if :    1)  I don't share the link to my app  and 2) if my Integromat account doesn't get hacked (or Integromat servers hacked).... is there some imminent danger for me by publishing the app and leaving the setting as External?  Sorry for being wordy but this quite confusing stuff for me.